# Unable to check private browsing for Android

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

We are developing an addon for Android mobile, using SDK1.17, where we need to check for private-browsing, but we are unable to do this. 
As of now we have gone through too many documentation pages to check for private window state/detection but none of the solution is working in case of Android Firefox.

Below are some implementation that we tried

```
1. require('sdk/private-browsing/utils').ignoreWindow(window)   : It always returning false when opted for private browsing and nothing was return in case of Private Window mode when NOT opted for private browsing
2. require("sdk/private-browsing").isPrivate(tab) : It always returning false when opted for private browsing 
3. Also checked other solutions on other forums
```

Device Details on which we are checking:
    1. Samsung - S4
    2. Android 4.4.2
    3. Firefox Nightly Build 39.0a1

Could you please suggest any solution for below expectations?
    1. We want to detach content script for private window in onAttach event of page-mod
    2. Want to identify if request/response is from/to private window (while intercepting request/response using observer)